# Lauch command from applescript into terminal one by one

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I try to launch a batch of commands from Applescript into terminal. I would like to execute each command only if the previous one is finished. And in the same terminal window. But for now, everything is executed at the same time in different terminal windows. This is my code :

PS : of course I just need the terminal to check the progression of the script. Without terminal, il works.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    delay 5
    do script "yes | sudo /opt/homebrew/Cellar/e2fsprogs/1.47.0/sbin/mkfs.ext2 -I 128 -L " & nomdisque & " " & diskPath & "s1\n"
    do script "diskutil mountDisk " & diskPath
    delay 5
    set mountpoint to do shell script "df -l | grep " & quoted form of diskPath & " | awk '{print $9}'"
    do script "diskutil mountDisk " & diskPath
    do script "sudo chmod -R +w " & quoted form of diskPath
    delay 5
    do script "sudo rsync -avP " & sourceFolder & " " & mountpoint
    do script "sudo chmod -R -w " & mountpoint
end tell
```

Comment: Can you put all your shell commands in a script and run the script with `do script ...` ?

Comment: As @Philippe suggests, it would be much clearer to do the entire thing in a `bash` script.

Comment: Indeed it could be simpler, but before that I need a Applescript to do some tasks. So this part of the script is in the middle of a Applescript.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, you can specify which tab/window a command is run in. If you don't specify, then apparently a new window is used. Of course, you can also find out what the id of the window is and use that to be more specific (in case you have multiple windows open).

From the Terminal dictionary:

> **do script** v : Runs a UNIX shell script or command
>
> **do script** [text] : The command to execute.
>
> [**in** tab, window, or any] : The tab in which to execute the command
>
> → tab : The tab the command was executed in.

Example:

```
    do script "cd ~/Desktop" in tab 1 of window 1
    do script "cd ~/Desktop" in tab 1 of window id 3599
```

Second, in most shells, you can divide commands using a semi-colon or double ampersand (&&). You can read about it in Apple's [technical note TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-DOES_CHANGING_THE_ENVIRONMENT_IN_ONE_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT_AFFECT_THE_ENVIRONMENT_OF_OTHER_ONES_) under `Does changing the environment in one…`.

Here is an example that plays part of an mp3 mid-way through the script and then proceeds to the remaining lines.

```
set ff to quoted form of POSIX path of file "MacHD:Users:username:Downloads:radio1.mp3"
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd ~/Desktop && pwd && /opt/local/bin/mpv --start=-5 " & ff & " && cd ~/Documents && pwd" in tab 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Terminal output:

```
--> 
% cd ~/Desktop
%      pwd
/Users/username/Desktop
%      cd ~/Documents
%      pwd
/Users/username/Documents
```

Comment: You are correct about chaining commands together with a `;`.  Keep in mind that `[command-a] ; [command-b] ` means to  run command A and then B, regardless of success of A.  It looks as if the code in the OP's example, for the most part, each command depends on the previous command to succeed. Therefore, instead of using a `;` to chain the commands,  using `&&` instead would mean... `[command-a] && [command-b]` (Run command B if A succeeded)

Comment: @wch1zpink Good point. My example should have included a command that would fail. Thanks.

Comment: Hello thank's : but this line doesn't seem to work in a chain commande :  set mountpoint to do shell script "df -l | grep " & quoted form of diskPath & " | awk '{print $9}'"

Comment: Lot's of things don't work. What does it do? And what is *diskPath*? —specifically, not generally.

Comment: I set diskPath to "/" and inserted the df/awk commands before the final 'pwd' in the script and it worked fine. Can you advise as to what happens when you run the script?

Comment: Hello thank's, and sorry I wasn't precise enought. After few test I "discovered" the problem came from "set mountpoint" because this is the Applescript way to set a variable... so I had just to remove : set mountpoint to do shell script and replace by : mountpoint=$(df -l | grep " & quoted form of diskPath & " | awk '{print $9}'")